# Something is going wrong with my procedure in Oracle, day of week problem

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named `MEAKEL` with two columns:

```
ID  NUMBER(3,0)
DAY VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
```

A row will look like this:

```
111, sunday
```

I got a procedure to get the key and compare it to current day

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_key_day(p_key IN NUMBER) IS
  v_day VARCHAR2(10);
  v_today VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT DAY INTO v_day
  FROM MEAKEL
  WHERE ID = p_key;
  
  v_today := LOWER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'day'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_day = ' || v_day);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today = ' || v_today);

  IF v_day != v_today THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'The day stored in the table does not match today''s day');
  END IF;
END;

set serveroutput on
BEGIN
check_key_day(111);
END;
```

Actually the two `output.put_line` return "sunday":

```
v_day = sunday
Today = sunday
```

I have no idea why RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is raised because the condition is when NOT EQUAL, ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can retry by using `TRIM(v_day) != v_today` as an option, since we don't know whether there exist whitespace(s) surrounding the value within the table. Btw, using `LOWER` for `LOWER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'day'))` is redundant, as the format mask `day` already would return the results all in lower case letters.

Comment: thanks but I actually did something else :> , I was asked to store days in that table, doesnt matter if as varchar or a number..
so instead of wasting my time Im referring the days as 1 2 3 and it works fine:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **date format model** you used that bothers you. `'day'` returns day name, but it is right-padded with spaces up to length of the longest day name, which means that all days names have the same length (see `day_name_length` column in example that follows; all values are `9`). It means that your code would work on wednesdays.

But, if you used `'fmday'`, then you'd get a different result and comparison of current day name and value stored in table would work *every day*.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'day') || '#' day_1,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'fmday') || '#' day_2
  3  from dual;

DAY_1                                 DAY_2
------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
sunday   #                            sunday#
      ---    
      'day': see spaces here?         'fmday': no spaces
```

---

```
SQL> with temp (datum) as
  2    (select sysdate + level - 1
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 7
  5    )
  6  select to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_1,
  7    to_char(datum, 'day') day_name,
  8    length(to_char(datum, 'day')) day_name_length,
  9    --
 10    to_char(datum, 'fmday') day_name_2,
 11    length(to_char(datum, 'fmday')) day_name_length_2
 12  from temp
 13  order by datum;

DATE_1     DAY_NAME     DAY_NAME_LENGTH DAY_NAME_2   DAY_NAME_LENGTH_2
---------- ------------ --------------- ------------ -----------------
12.02.2023 sunday                     9 sunday                       6
13.02.2023 monday                     9 monday                       6
14.02.2023 tuesday                    9 tuesday                      7
15.02.2023 wednesday                  9 wednesday                    9
16.02.2023 thursday                   9 thursday                     8
17.02.2023 friday                     9 friday                       6
18.02.2023 saturday                   9 saturday                     8
                                      ^                              ^
7 rows selected.                      |                              |
                                    'day'                          'fmday'
SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I ended up trimming and everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Ive done the following eventually instead of trying to compare sunday with sunday Im comparing 1 with 1, and it seems to be working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_key_day(p_key IN NUMBER) IS
  v_day number(1);
  v_today number(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT DAY INTO v_day
  FROM MEAKEL
  WHERE ID = p_key;
  
   v_today := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D');

  IF v_day != v_today THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'The day stored in the table does not match today''s day');
  END IF;
END;


set serveroutput on
BEGIN
check_key_day(102);
END;


CREATE TABLE MEAKEL (
    ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    DAY NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MEAKEL_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Littlefoot's approach is safer; the 'D' date format element is NLS-dependent, so you will get unexpected results if someone happens to call your procedure from a session defined in a territory - 1 is Sunday in some places and Monday in others. Even with 'day', someone with a different date language will get the wrong result, but you can override that with the optional third argument to `to_char()` - [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225035/266304).

Comment: Storing a number or a day of the week is a BAD idea as they can be easily calculated ie look at @Littlefoot example. I would recommend storing either a DATE or TIMESTAMP.. in your model what would you do if someone wanted 1 in your table to represent say a SUNDAY or a MONDAY...

Comment: thanks both, apppreciate your replies